# How to make an expandable navigation rail that overlaps with other widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i made a simple program, wherein i have an expandable navigation rail thats expands on mouse hove and a pdf viewer in the main body.

It works but not exactly how i expected it to be, what i expected for it to happen is when the navigation rail expands i want it to overlap into the pdf viewer.

```
class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {

  int _index = 0;
  int get index => _index;
  set index(int index) => setState(() => _index = index);

  bool _expanded = false;
  bool get expanded => _expanded;
  set expanded(bool expanded) => setState(() => _expanded = expanded);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Nav Drawer'),
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 146, 212, 241),
      ),
      body: Row(
        children: [
          MouseRegion(
            onEnter: (_) => expanded = true,
            onExit: (_) => expanded = false,

            child: NavigationRail(
              selectedIndex: index,
              extended: expanded,
              onDestinationSelected: (i) => index = i,

              destinations: const [
                NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.one_k), label: Text("one")),
                NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.two_k), label: Text("two")),
                NavigationRailDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.three_k), label: Text("three")),
              ],
            ),
          ),

          Expanded(
            child: Column (
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(child: SfPdfViewer.network('https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf')),
              ]
            )
          ),
          
        ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here are images of the app (Im having problems with uploading images)

- [Image](https://i.ibb.co/2MbSmtv/image.png) for base state
- [Image](https://i.ibb.co/pxsHJyv/image.png) for the mouse hover state, notice the pdf is pushed to the right.
- [Image](https://i.ibb.co/hfZg6zb/image.png) for the un-hover state, notice the pdf doesnt return to its full size, it only returns to its full size when the mouse is moved in the pdf view

What properties can i use to make it overlap to the pdf view ?

Comment: Typically you'd use a [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) for layering elements

Comment: @Wh1t3rabbit thanks for the suggestion, but there is 1 concern i immediately thought of just testing it out. it looks like im forced to put the nav rail into a sized box and set a width value which i assume would break its dynamic sizing. also it seems to break my implementation of the expanding. I will try to play with it more to iron some kinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you wanted. It's an overlapping NavigationRail. It will keep in its position forever & it will neither interfere with the PDF viewer & nor move aside from the PDF viewer. It's the sticky.

```
import "package:flutter/gestures.dart";
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer/pdfviewer.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: MyWidget());
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int index = 0;
  bool expanded = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 72.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: SfPdfViewer.network(
                      "https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf",
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                MouseRegion(
                  onEnter: (PointerEnterEvent event) {
                    expanded = true;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  onHover: (PointerHoverEvent event) {},
                  onExit: (PointerExitEvent event) {
                    expanded = false;
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: NavigationRail(
                    selectedIndex: index,
                    extended: expanded,
                    destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.one_k),
                        label: Text("one"),
                      ),
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.two_k),
                        label: Text("two"),
                      ),
                      NavigationRailDestination(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.three_k),
                        label: Text("three"),
                      ),
                    ],
                    onDestinationSelected: (int i) {
                      index = i;
                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It works great sir ! Thank you so much. A question: why did you use row with a single widget as its children? Is it so that it wont occupy the whole screen? i would think that it would automatically occupy the whole row ( this is happened to me while i was trying things out)

Comment: There are two reasons. First, it won't work without providing a row as a parent & second, you can put another widget over there. I mean alongside the navigation rail (if you want), for example, vertical divider, etc.

Comment: So mouseregion does not work if its not inside a row? well thats weird